BluetoothLE with Android 33 - no GATT events after writeDescriptor
With Android < 13, my app was able to connect to my Bluetooth device and everything worked. Now I had to upgrade to 13, an see following behaviour: the device connects but shortly after it gets into a loop of disconnects and connects.
I found that the problem starts with a call to writeDescriptor directly after the service discovery, where I want to enable notifications.
byte[] newDescriptorValue = enable ? BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE : BluetoothGattDescriptor.DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE;
int r = bluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor1, newDescriptorValue);
result = r == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS;

The GATTCallback never gets called. Neither the onDescriptorWrite nor the onCharacteristicChanged. A timeout then triggers the disconnect.
I updated the GATTCallback to use the new callback functions for Android 13 instead of the old ones.
What am I missing?
Here is some code:
this.setOnServicesFound(()->
    {      
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = getNotifiable(serviceUUID, characteristicUUID, true);
        setNotificationState(characteristic, true);
    });

and
public boolean setNotificationState(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, boolean enable) {
      if (!this.gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enable)) {
        return false;
      }        

    UUID GATT_CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIGURATION = uuidFromString("2902");
    final BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(GATT_CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIGURATION);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    {
        int res = this.gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor, enable ? BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE : BluetoothGattDescriptor.DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        return res == GATT_SUCCESS;
    }
    else {
        descriptor.setValue(enable ? BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE : BluetoothGattDescriptor.DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        return this.gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
    }
}

These are from the logs (after services where found and I try to enable notifications on the characteristic):
smp_proc_pairing_cmpl: Pairing process has failed to   remote:xx:xx:xx:xx:21:3e smp_reason:UNKNOWN[113] sec_level:0x0

BTM_ReadDevInfo: Determining device_type:BLE addr_type:public

btif_storage_remove_ble_bonding_keys: Removing bonding keys for bd addr:00:00:00:00:00:00

get_cod: get_cod remote_cod = 0x00001f00

bond_state_changed: Bond state changed to state=0 [0:none, 1:bonding, 2:bonded], prev_state=0, sdp_attempts = 0

[ERROR:metric_id_allocator.cc(184)] BluetoothMetricIdAllocatorFailed to forget device because device is not in paired_device_cache_

[INFO:gatt_utils.cc(1500)] gatt_end_operation status=137 op=3 subtype=2

onConnectionUpdated() - Device=xx:xx:xx:xx:21:3E interval=39    latency=0 timeout=500 status=0


Are there any errors or log output related to this issue? Does your application check that it has all the necessary permissions granted by the user?

All necessary permissions are granted.

And what is about the log?

I updated my question and included some logs.

is your app goes in onpause state ? when it disconnects ?

No, the app does not go in pause
